# Follow up question, Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Extension with n mean-reversion values

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Hi this Question follows after the answer of [Douglas Zare](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12327/extension-of-some-feature-of-sde-ornstein-uhlenbeck-type) to this post :

So let's be given a positive function $V(x)$ which is smooth enough to have Lispchitzian derivative at all point. Moreover this function admits multiple zeros denoted $(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$ and let $X_t$ the diffusion process following the stochastic equation below :

$dX_t=V'(X_t)dt + \sigma.dW_t$ where now $\sigma$ is a constant (but will later be replaced by some function of $X_t$)
and $X_0=x$

Here are my questions :

1-What are the conditions on $V$ for $X_t$ :

a- to admit a stationary distribution ? and does this distribution can be explicited in terms of $V,x,\theta_1,...,\theta_n$, and $\sigma$ ?

b- to be an ergodic process ?

2-What are the smoothness conditions on $\sigma$ (now a function of $X_t$) to keep 1/a- or 1/b- true ?

Of course any reference is welcome if the answer is too long for a single post.

Best Regards

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to make the title more descriptive.

Comment: Is it better now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us assume you are interested in the solution of $dX_t=\sigma(X_t)dW_t+b(X_t)dt$. If the so-called *speed measure* $m$ has finite mass, the diffusion converges in distribution to $m/|m|$. Here, $m(x)=2/(\sigma^2(x)s'(x))$ where $s$ is the so-called *scale* of the diffusion. Recall that $s$ is uniquely defined, up to affine transformations, as the solution of the differential equation $\frac12\sigma(x)^2s''(x)+b(x)s'(x)=0$.

In your case, $\sigma$ is constant and $b(\cdot)=V'(\cdot)$, hence $s'(x)=\exp(-2V(x)/\sigma^2)$ up to a multiplicative constant. The condition for ergodicity is that the function $\exp(2V(\cdot)/\sigma^2)$ is integrable. In that case, the stationary distribution is proportional to this function.

Comment: And the generalization to non constant functions $\sigma(\cdot)$ is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks,great and very clear answer. By the way do you have some references about "speed measures" and "scale functions" that you would recommand ?
Regards 

Comment: I was afraid you would ask this question... A classic reference is the venerable *Diffusions, Markov Processes and Martingales: Volume 2, Itô Calculus* by Rogers and Williams but it might take time to digest. Durrett, as often, is most congenial and you could try his book *Stochastic calculus* (which I believe has a whole chapter devoted to 1D diffusions, but I do not have the book at hand so, if the chapter exists it will deal with this stuff and otherwise, well, I apologize in advance).

Comment: Please do not apologize, I know this reference but couldn't remember that it has the subject treated. I should re-read it then. Regards